# R, getting the Subset of row vectors in a Matrix

Tags: r, vector, matrix, subset

in R, I want to create a matrix which is a subset of a matrix `mat2` based on some criteria stored in another vector `km$cluster$`. Specifically, I want to get a subset of `mat2` where the row names from `km$cluster[km$cluster == 3]` (that is the vectors in cluster 3 from a kmeans clustering) are equal to the row names in `mat2`

1. How do I get this subset of `mat2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work? Lemme know if it doesn't. First, get all the relevant row names:

```
clust3 <- row.names(km$cluster[km$cluster == 3])
```

Now use `subset` to get to where you need:

```
subset(mat2, row.names(mat2) %in% clust3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mat2[which(km$cluster == 3), , drop=FALSE]
```

Should work, assuming that row i of km corresponds to row i of mat2

Comment: Use `drop = FALSE` to stop automatic coercion to a vector when `length(which(km$cluster == 3))==1L`